# How to obtain static url in Django Views

Tags: javascript, python, django

I was wondering how to access to the website STATIC url from views in Django, because i have to send to the frontend the link of a static resource.

I've tried using

```
os.path.join(settings.STATIC_ROOT, 'app/images/edit.png')
```

But i'm having troubles loading the resource, in fact, this approach gives me this error in javascript console:

```
Not allowed to load local resource ...[PATH OF FILE]...
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `STATIC_ROOT` is the location on the disk. Try using `STATIC_URL` instead.

Answer (score 2):

You can use static in views by:

```
from django.contrib.staticfiles.templatetags.staticfiles import static
image_path = static('app/images/edit.png')
```

static is the same function you use in templates.
as in templates, static() return relative path, if you want absolute url:

```
image_path = static('app/images/edit.png')
absolute_image_path = request.build_absolute_uri(image_path)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could load static files easily in django template. I'm quoting the example [django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/) gives:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<img src="{% static "my_app/myexample.jpg" %}" alt="My image"/>
```

Comment: I know, but i need to send to the template the complete path without using the template tags!